# Display numbers as subscript in selected items from v-select slot in vue js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I use `v-select` in Vue project to select from Chemicals and oxides list,
I want to display selected items with Subscript for numbers only like attached figure **:**

[image]

My code is **:**

```
<v-select v-model="elements" class="form-control text-left" :items="chemicals"></v-select>
```

chemicals **:**

```
["Ag","Al2O3","Al2O3/(CaO+MgO+K2O+Na2O)","As","Au","Ba","BaO","Be","Bi","Br","Ca","CaO","Cd","Ce","Cl","Cl","Co","CO2","Cr","Cr2O3","Cs","Cu","Dy","SO3","SO4","Sr","SrO","Ta","Tb","Th","Ti","TiO2","Tl",]
```

Comment: Can you use the subscripts unicode characters in your strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace all the digits as individual subscript characters:

1. Create an array (e.g., named `subscripts`) of subscript Unicode characters (`\u2080` for `0`, through `u2089` for `9`). This enables mapping a given digit to a subscript character by using the digit as an index into the subscript array (i.e., `subscripts[3] = '\u2083'`).
2. Use [`String.prototype.replace()` with a replacer function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) that converts  any digit to the subscript.

```js
const subscripts = [
  '\u2080',
  '\u2081',
  '\u2082',
  '\u2083',
  '\u2084',
  '\u2085',
  '\u2086',
  '\u2087',
  '\u2088',
  '\u2089',
]

const ELEMENTS = ["Ag","Al2O3","Al2O3/(CaO+MgO+K2O+Na2O)","As","Au","Ba","BaO","Be","Bi","Br","Ca","CaO","Cd","Ce","Cl","Cl","Co","CO2","Cr","Cr2O3","Cs","Cu","Dy","SO3","SO4","Sr","SrO","Ta","Tb","Th","Ti","TiO2","Tl"]

const elements = ELEMENTS.map(name => {
  return name.replace(/\d/g, (num) => subscripts[Number(num)])
})
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/yLpYLYX)

[image: screenshot]